# can't connect mongodb in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I can't connect mongodb on server with debian and python 2.6.6 on this line:

```
connection = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://localhost', safe = True)
```

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'

The same code works on window machine with python 2.7.3.
Could you please explain how to correct this error?

I have pymongo version 2.3 on machine where it works and 1.7 where it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of pymongo do you use on your servers?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get pymongo version?

Comment: I tried on server: pymongo.__dict__['version']. It shows: 1.7

Comment: import pymongo; print pymongo.version

Comment: pymongo 1.7 does not have 'safe' parameter of the 'Connection' method. Moreover this version is really old one. You should look for a updating.

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/connection.html

Comment: Coyld you tell how to install pymongo 2.3 on debian?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19086/discussion-between-alexvassel-and-user366534)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using different versions of pymongo.

Comment: Could you explan what you mean? You answer is not concrete and doesn't answer the question now.

Comment: your question does not actually explain the problem. How many machines do you use? We suppose that there are two machines: with python 2.6 and with python 2.7. Right?

Comment: Yes, that true. One windows machine with 2.7 (script works on it) and one debian with python 2.6 (where script doesn't work)

Comment: check versions on every machine.

Comment: I have pymongo version 2.3 on machine where it works and 1.7 where it doesn't work.

Comment: Coyld you tell how to install pymongo 2.3 on debian?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that both servers have the same pymongo version installed. Likely a version mismatch with slightly different parameter lists for the Connection constructor.

Comment: import pymongo; print pymongo.version

Comment: On server I have version 1.7.

Comment: Coyld you tell how to install pymongo 2.3 on debian?